# ASP.net with C# where to add a method for list box that is the total price of each cartitem (Unit price * quantity)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a product page that on click event brings a selected product with price from a sql data source and it also allows the user to add a quantity. I send it to a list box on a new page called cart and display it with this which s part of the cartitem class

```
public string Display()
{
    return cproduct.Description + " (" + cquantity.ToString() + " at " + cproduct.UnitPrice.ToString("c") 
        + " each) " ;
}
```

and this from the cart.aspx.cs page

```
public partial class Cart : System.Web.UI.Page
{
CartItemList cart;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cart = CartItemList.GetCart();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.DisplayCart();
    }
}
protected void DisplayCart()
{
    lstCart.Items.Clear();
    CartItem item;
    for (int i = 0; i < cart.count; i++)
    {
        item = cart[i];
        lstCart.Items.Add(item.Display());
    }
}
```

I want to add to this is a total of each item at the end (Unit price * Quantity).
But what I can't seem to figure out is where exactly would I add this.  I have product.aspx page and a cart.aspx page with the list box and the behind the code page for each..  Product page is a simple drop down list from a sql database and a text box to enter the quantity in.  I've got a cartitem, cartitemlist, and product class. I'd post more code but I figured that would not be necessary but I can if needed.  Any help would be so very appreciated because I'm going grey over it.  Thanks
Lynda

Comment: for your String Concat use `strng.Format` also here is a good site that will give examples on how to format numeric values. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: are you also wanting to create a separate method that calculates the totals..

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and the website link.  I'd been there a few times for other problems but not this.  I'm definitely all new at this part and appreciate you taking your time to help me out.

Comment: Lynda I see you are located in North Richland Hills I am in McKinney I work in Down Town Ft Worth.. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could just tack it on to the display method:

```
public string Display()
{
    return cproduct.Description + " (" + cquantity.ToString() + " at " + cproduct.UnitPrice.ToString("c") + " each) Total  " + (cquantity*cproduct.UnitPrice).ToString("c") ;
}
```

Though honestly I am a bit confused as to why you are using a list box for this? It just seems an odd choice. I'd probably do a listview with a table or a datalist, which would give you a lot of functionality for free (like the ability to edit quantities and delete lines).

Comment: Thank you that did it.  Was trying to be way more complicated apparently. Thank you so very much for taking the time out to help me.  Hope you have a great day.